# hide text from inbox preview MailChimp

Tags: html-email, mailchimp

While I have added inbox preview text for MailChimp, I would like to stop it also showing the 'view this email in your browser text' in the inbox preview text.

Is there a way to hide text from inbox preview in an html template for Mailchimp?

Comment: It looks like you're asking a question, but you're not posting any html code which we could use to help answer that question. How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this you will need a pre-header. A pre-header is a line of code you place just after the `<body>` opening tag which hides whatever is in it visually. Doing this - you can have what you want to display in the email preview without taking in any of the miscellaneous content (for example view in browser links).

```
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
<span style="display:none !important; visiblility:hidden; opacity:0px; color:transparent; height:0px; width:0px; mso-hide:all; max-height:0px; max-width:0px; line-height:0px; overflow:hidden;">Type your teaser content here.</span>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

In the above example of a preheader, you can see many different things going on. First up we have the `<!--[if !mso]><!-->` snippet. This will ensure anything encased between that and the `<!--<![endif]-->` statement will not be rendered in a Microsoft client. This is done because of Outlooks limited CSS support.

Next, we have a span stag with various CSS elements to hide the content within it. Then contained within the span tags is the content you'd want to appear in the preview of the email client.